# Adding extra information to dygraph legend?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is there an easy way to be able to add extra data to the dygraph legend?

I obviously want to display the x & y data values, but the underlying data point holds extra information that I want to show to the user.

I can obviously use the callback option to find out what point has been moused over .  So is the only option to use the callback and then have my own div which shows this information rather than using the dygraph legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the [`legendFormatter` option](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683) in the upcoming 2.0.0 release:

```
function legendFormatter(data) {
  if (data.x == null) return '';  // no selection
  return data.xHTML +
      data.series
      .map(v => v.labelHTML + ': ' + v.yHTML)  // modify as needed
      .join(' ');
}

new Dygraph(div, data, { legendFormatter });
```

Comment: How would you apply that to a Shiny script ? By installing the js extension and binding this js function to a dyCallback ?